# Making a FormikInput show its value over multiple lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik

I am working on an older project. As part of a form the user puts in a text - this text might be longer then the input field is wide. Therefore this field should be stretching over multiple lines to show all its content. It is no problem to make the field bigger, but the content is still only displayed in one line and then cut off.

```
<div className="small-12 medium-12 large-12">{this.renderCloze()}</div>
    <FormikInput
         label="Zusatzinformation"
         name="checklist.additionalInfo"
         readOnly={!!checklist.completed}
         rows="2"
         type="text"
         size="large"
     />
```

Thats the part where the input field is created. This is the FormikInput:

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field } from 'formik';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import FormInput from './FormInput';

export default class FormikInput extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        component: PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.element,
            PropTypes.elementType,
            PropTypes.string,
        ]),
        label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        size: PropTypes.string,
    };

    handleOnChange = (event, onChange) => {
        if (!event || !event.target) {
            console.warn('FormikInput: empty event', event);
        }
        onChange && onChange(event);
    };

    render() {
        const { name, component, ...childProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <Field name={name}>
                {({ field }) => (
                    <FormInput
                        {...field}
                        component={component}
                        errorMessage={<ErrorMessage name={this.props.name} component="div" />}
                        {...childProps}
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleOnChange(event, field.onChange)}
                    />
                )}
            </Field>
        );
    }
}
```

FormInput.js:

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

export default class FormInput extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

        component: PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.element,
            PropTypes.elementType,
            PropTypes.node,
            PropTypes.string,
        ]),
        errorMessage: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.element, PropTypes.node, PropTypes.string]),
        size: PropTypes.string,
        value: PropTypes.any,
    };

    className = () => {
        if (this.props.size === 'large') {
            return 'small-12 medium-12 large-12';
        }
        if (this.props.size === 'medium') {
            return 'small-12 medium-6 large-6';
        }
        if (this.props.size === 'third') {
            return 'small-12 medium-6 large-4';
        }
        return this.props.size ? this.props.size : '';
    };

    id = () => {
        if (this.props.id) {
            return this.props.id;
        }
        if (this.props.name) {
            return 'FormField__' + this.props.name;
        }
        return 'FormField__' + Math.random().toString(36);
    };

    render() {
        let { label, errorMessage, component, size, ...childProps } = this.props;
        childProps.id = this.id();
        if (!component) {
            component = 'input';
            childProps.type = 'text';
        }
        const input = React.isValidElement(component)
            ? React.cloneElement(component, childProps)
            : React.createElement(component, childProps);

        return (
            <div className={this.className()}>
                <div className="group">
                    {input}
                    <label htmlFor={this.id()}>{this.props.label}</label>
                </div>
                {typeof this.props.errorMessage === 'string' ? (
                    <div>{this.props.errorMessage}</div>
                ) : (
                    this.props.errorMessage
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#multiline

Comment: @SethLutske Thanks for the link, but I already seen that page and didnt manage to solve my problem with the info provided.

Comment: just FYI, your last 2 code blocks are the same codeblock...we still don't know whats inside `FormInput`

Comment: @SethLutske Thanks. Now i provided the right code ^^

Comment: I am pretty new to JavaScript - at the moment it looks like building a new textarea for displaying is the only viable solution

Comment: Looks like through all your crazy logic, you're rendering an html `<input>` (with `component = 'input'`).  You should try switching to a proper html `<textarea>`.

Comment: yeah thats what i was talking about @SethLutske . My initial question was if its possible to modify only the input element to display its contents over multiple lines. If thats not possible textarea seems like the best option to me. But this whole Formik stuff is 100% new to me. And i only just got the basics of html, css and js. Changing the component='input' to ='textarea' doesnt work :(